# Const in React always has value "Default : Object"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using SlateJS and trying to load data into a const using: `imgData = data.get("file");`

This works fine if I don't import React, but when React is imported the object contains the value below. What is this value? How does this happen? How do I avoid this?

```
default: Object
  Children: Object
  Component: ReactComponent(props, context, updater)
  DOM: Object
  PropTypes: Object
  PureComponent: ReactPureComponent(props, context, updater)
  __spread: ()
  cloneElement: (element, props, children)
  createClass: (spec)
  createElement: (type, props, children)
  createFactory: (type)
  createMixin: (mixin)
  isValidElement: (object)
  version: "15.4.1"
  __proto__: Object
  __proto__: Object
```

Thanks very much for any help you can provide.

Comment: what is this "file" ?

Comment: It's a blob containing an image. The const imgData contains the blob after I do the data.get, unless I import ReactJS, at which point it instead contains what I pasted above.

Comment: i think importing react is assigning this keyword.

Comment: That is strange behavior. Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce it?

Answer (score -2):

use this it would really help you:

```
imgData = JSON.stringify(data.get("file"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but the issue is that the object contains the entirely wrong values, not that I need it stringified. The object should contain just a blob with properties of type and size.